# How to change colour of snowshovel particles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map in minecraft and I'm unable to colour the snowshovel particle. I want to colour them red. I searched the Internet but the only thing I found was 'How to colour reddust particles'. So is there any way I can colour snowshovel particles. I'm using minecraft 1.10.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem before on my server, and here's how I did it. I'll try to include as much info as I know. Take note that in second case only **reddust**, **mobSpell** and **mobSpellAmbient** can be setup in colours.

But first, do you want to *colour the particle when a player does a thing that triggers it* or you want to *summon a coloured particle*?

1. If you want to do the first case, you have to make a resource pack, so Minecraft changes colour or texture (or whatever you did to them) of **all** the edited particles. Be aware in order to summon the normal particle you **may** need to check out the other way stated here.
   Here's a nice link to making texture (resource) packs:
   https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack
2. If you need to *summon* a particle that is modified, use command blocks. Command you are looking for is `/particle` and it's parameters are this:

   ```
    /particle name x y z xd yd zd speed [count] [player]
   ```

So, parameters not surrounded are **needed** and ones surrounded by [] are **optional**.

`NAME` - Here you put the name of the desired particle. [Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Particles) you can see a list of all the particles with their respective names.

`X, Y, Z` - Here you specify where to **summon** the particle. You insert them without the commas.

`XD, YD, ZD` - Here you put the parameter of the *cuboid* to be filled. It is centered in coordinates X Y Z you previously entered. Every parameter is multiplied by 8 so if you enter 1 1 1 as XD XY XZ, you will get a 8x8x8 cube.

Now **here's the catch**.
In case of reddust, mobSpell and mobSpellAmbient, and speed is not 0, and count is 0 or not specified, these values are set as the RGB channel values of the color of the particle, and are specified in the range 0 to 1. In this usage, the speed parameter acts as a multiplier on these values. If count is greater than 0 for those particles, xd yd zd are treated as a 3-dimensional volume as usual, rather than as a color, and randomized colors are used.

`SPEED` - Determines the particle speed (how long it lingers).

`COUNT` - Determined how many particles to create.

`PLAYER` - Determines which players to see the particle.

Last two are not required.

**So, if you really want to use snowshovel you have to colour them by making your resource pack! But, if you can switch them with any of the 3 exceptions, you can colour them, taking care that XD, XY and XZ are RGB coded colours.**